# Hook the function in module in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6, hook

How can I make changes to the function `uc_order_view_update_form($form_state, $order)`? This exists in `ubercart\uc_order\uc_order.order_pane.inc`. I dont know how to make hook for this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely modify any form in Drupal from a custom module using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6).